# IndicatingAjaxButton works only once

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have derived a class from IndicatingAjaxButton (which is the button to a form). But the IAjaxIndicatorAware does only work once, i.e. if the validation of the form fails I print feedback messages within the form. During the 1st request the "onProgress-Circle" is shown. But if I click on the button again (after I made the right input on the form), there is no "onProgress-Circle" anymore.

I took a look in the generated HTML:
1) Before the first click, there is a img tag, which gets displayed when the request is started
2) After the first request is processed, this img tag is removed.

This are the evaluation steps that are returned from the server:

```
<evaluate><![CDATA[var e = Wicket.$('previouse--ajax-indicator'); if (e != null && typeof(e.parentNode) != 'undefined') e.parentNode.removeChild(e);]]></evaluate>
```

This I guess leads to removing all childs from the button, also the img tag. Is this a bug or do I use the button in a wrong way?

I use Wicket 1.5

Thanks and kind regards,
Soccertrash

Comment: Got the solution:

One has to add only the form component to the AjaxRequestTarget and not the button itself (I added a whole panel containing also the button itself).

Comment: Please add this as an answer, not a comment. That way, you can accept an answer for this question and it won't appear to be unanswered on the questions list.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug related to this which is fixed in 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution: One has to add only the form component to the AjaxRequestTarget and not the button itself (I added a whole panel containing also the button itself)